# [ERROR]:CallNamedPipe failed. Error=2 (Qt)

Tags: windows, qt, qt-creator

After open a new Qt GUI application project, I run this new project directly without adding any code or changing any settings, however I always get an error message :

**[ERROR]:CallNamedPipe failed. Error=2**

[image]

And this is the screen shot of running the same project in the debug mode:

[image]

It seems that the GUI can run successfully but I really don’t have a clue where this error might come from.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Error code 2 is ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. It appears that something in the Qt library is calling `CallNamedPipe` and passing a pipe name that is not recognised. So the call to `CallNamedPipe` fails and returns an error code to indicate why. 

However, this is all perfectly normal. The Qt library is just checking to see if there is anything at the other end of the named pipe. If there is presumably it would write to it. Your program runs fine, nothing to worry about.

Comment: Might also have to do with the QtCreator<->test.exe communication setup. Check if you get qDebug() output from the application (in a debug build)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: if it was a warning, perhaps it would be OK, not sure. But seeing an error is suboptimal IMO.

Comment: @Frank:I just run the project in the debug mode, however I'm getting the same error message : "[ERROR]:CallNamedPipe failed. Error=2". I also edit my question with the screenshot of the debug mode result, please let me know if there's any other approaches to check where this message could come from, thanks!

Comment: What problems are you experiencing? Does the program work? Does the debugger work?

Comment: @David:No, so far it seems the GUI can run well and the program is working fine. I’m having this question for this error message never shows before. When I started to use Qt-Creator, all my applications could run successfully without any error messages, and someday this message just pop out and it confuses me since I didn’t make any changes. Yes I understand since the program can still work it’s not a major issue, however I still want to know if there’s anything I can look into such as environmental settings to make it go away, thanks!