# [ERROR]: CallNamedPipe failed. Error=2 (Qt)

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I get the following error every time I run my program in Qt-Creator

`[ERROR]: CallNamedPipe failed. Error=2`

Usually twice: once at startup and again at shutdown.

I found the error is related to QtCreator itself, as running the same compiled program from the console, it do not generate this message.

I also found it is probably related to some configuration or miss-configuration as the installation on my other machine do not produce this behavior.

Related to: 
[[ERROR]:CallNamedPipe failed. Error=2 (Qt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968829/errorcallnamedpipe-failed-error-2-qt)

Minimal snippet that produce this behavior:

Project:

```
QT += core
TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Code:

```
#include <QDebug>
int main(int , char *[])
{
    qDebug() << "Hellow world!";
    return 0;
}
```

Is not that it is very annoying, as the software work correctly and the debugger more or less correctly. But that fill the log with those 2 lines again and again.

I tried to install a messageHandler (qInstallMessageHandler()) but the error is printed outside its scope.

Where this message come from? and more important: how to avoid it?

Additional info: I am on Windows (sad). I have the same behavior using G++ and MSVC2013

Comment: Asking Qt support, they do not seem to be aware of this error, and they are unable to reproduce it. 
I would like any user with this problem to comment: QT version, Operating system and time using the Qt-creator install.
Thanks you.